# Merge two columns in the same df together with sep = "."

Tags: r, merge

I have got a df with 19 columns and now I want to merge two columns (`df$klasse` and `df$grp`) with class `integer` together in R in such a way that the elements are put next to each other (`df$KG`), not below each other, separated with ".". Like shown below:

```
> df
klasse   grp    KG
  1       1     1.1
  1       1     1.1
  1       2     1.2
  1       2     1.2
  2       1     2.1
```

I guess it is possible, since a lot is possible in R. However, I have not been able to find a solution.. I tried looking into `cbind` but this does not seem to do what I want.. Now I found the function `reshape`, but I think this only works if you want to convert rows to columns (and the other way around). I am (still) a noob with regard to R, so if someone knows where to look or what to use, please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the result be numeric? If so, then

```
df$KG <- df$klasse + 0.1 * df$grp


> df
  klasse grp  KG
1      1   1 1.1
2      1   1 1.1
3      1   2 1.2
4      1   2 1.2
5      2   1 2.1
```

If you need the result to be character, then

```
df$KG1 <- paste(df$klasse, df$grp, sep='.')

> df
  klasse grp  KG KG1
1      1   1 1.1 1.1
2      1   1 1.1 1.1
3      1   2 1.2 1.2
4      1   2 1.2 1.2
5      2   1 2.1 2.1

> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ klasse: num  1 1 1 1 2
 $ grp   : num  1 1 2 2 1
 $ KG    : num  1.1 1.1 1.2 1.2 2.1
 $ KG1   : chr  "1.1" "1.1" "1.2" "1.2" ...
```

Comment: Yesss, that's it! I needed it to be character. Never thought it was this easy.. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
transform(df, KG=paste(klasse, grp, sep='.'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my approach:

```
mydf <- data.frame(klasse = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2), grp = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1))


mydf$KG <- paste(mydf$klasse, mydf$grp, sep=".") #pasting them together as character
mydf$KGnum <- as.numeric(mydf$KG) # converting the characters to numeric if needed


> mydf
  klasse grp  KG KGnum
1      1   1 1.1   1.1
2      1   1 1.1   1.1
3      1   2 1.2   1.2
4      1   2 1.2   1.2
5      2   1 2.1   2.1

> str(mydf)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ klasse: num  1 1 1 1 2
 $ grp   : num  1 1 2 2 1
 $ KG    : chr  "1.1" "1.1" "1.2" "1.2" ...
 $ KGnum : num  1.1 1.1 1.2 1.2 2.1
```

Comment: I think my numeric conversion is different than Alex's. It may be helpful to make the conversion even if the "grp" numerics have more than one digit. I'm not claiming to have a totally breaktrough approach, just something slightly different that may also be helfpul for the OP or other users.

Comment: Neither is it mine.. The `chr` is the same, but your `numeric` seems different. Thanks anyways for bothering!